# Генерация целых чисел разного знака

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Как сгенерировать рандомные числа с минусами и плюсами?

Comment: Генерировать только положительные и потом вычитать из них некоторое число, очевидно же.

Comment: arr[i]=(int)((Math.round(Math.random())*101-100); так будет правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(200) -100;
```

минимум `-100` и максимум `100`

---

после Java 1.7 можно делать так

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

// nextInt исключает максимальное значение,
// и нужно добавить 1 что бы включить
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

---

до Java 1.7 можно было и как функцию оформит. Взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/4953620)

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Максимальный и минимальный значения включены
 *
 * @param min Minimum value
 * @param max Maximum value.  Должен быть больше минимальной
 * @return Integer значения между min и max, включительно.
 * @see java.util.Random#nextInt(int)
 */
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // если Java 1.7 используйте ThreadLocalRandom
    Random rand;

    // nextInt исключает максимальное значение,
    // и нужно добавить 1 что бы включить
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо.